# Correct use of Lambda query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Consider the following code:

```
       private static void WriteProcesses(StreamWriter sw, DateTime d) {
            sw.WriteLine("List of processes @ " + d.ToString());
            Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses().Where(o => o.ProcessName.ToLower() != "svchost");            
            if(localAll.Length > 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < localAll.Length; i++) {                    
                    sw.WriteLine("      " + localAll[i].ProcessName);
                }
            }
        }
```

But i get a red squiggly line saying:

Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Diagnostics.Process[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I tried changing the array to a List but didnt work.

Comment: FYI, the generally accepted spelling is "lambda" ("lamda" is a little closer to the original greek but not the accepted English spelling).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses().Where(o => o.ProcessName.ToLower() != "svchost");
```

to

```
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses().Where(o => o.ProcessName.ToLower() != "svchost").ToArray();
```

`Where` is returning an `IEnumerable<Process>` on which you can call `ToArray` to convert to an array of type `Process`.

Alternatively, you can enumerate through the `IEnumerable<Process>` that `Where` returns.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(o => o.ProcessName.ToLower() != "svchost");
foreach (Process process in processes) {
    sw.WriteLine("      " + process.ProcessName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off to just deal with it as an IEnumerable

```
 private static void WriteProcesses(StreamWriter sw, DateTime d) {
     sw.WriteLine("List of processes @ " + d.ToString());
     var localAll = Process.GetProcesses()
                           .Where(o => o.ProcessName.ToLower() != "svchost");            
     foreach(Process process in localAll) {                    
         sw.WriteLine("      " + process.ProcessName);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
       private static void WriteProcesses(StreamWriter sw, DateTime d) {
            sw.WriteLine("List of processes @ " + d.ToString());
            var localAll = Process.GetProcesses().Where(o => o.ProcessName.ToLower() != "svchost");            
            foreach(var local in localAll) {                    
                    sw.WriteLine("      " + local.ProcessName);
            }
        }
```

Your problem is coming from the fact that `Where` returns an `IEnumerable` which cannot be mapped to an array. But there is no need for you to use an array so I've taken the use of it out. The `length` check is just making the code less clear for me so I changed to a `foreach` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ToArray(), change Process[] to var then hover over it to see what type is being returned from the Where statement. (Or just hover over the Where() method, which will tell you the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

The .Where method returns an IEnumerable, where T is the type being filtered. For this example you would need to call .ToArray( ) after the Where to convert the collection to an array.